# use DISTINCT clause in WHERE clause in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to select from table 1(or update certain records) `where distinct(make, model,category) = distinct(make, model,category) in table 2`
i tried this:

```
select * from t1 
having ( make, model, catcode) = (select  make, model, catcode from t2)
```

and tried this as well:

```
select * from t1
where (make, model, catcode) in (select make, model, catcode from t2)
```

but both are not working 
any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunalely `IN` and `=` only support single-column results.  You can do what you want with an `EXISTS`:

```
select * from t1 
WHERE EXISTS( 
    SELECT null FROM t2 
    WHERE t1.make = t2.make
      AND t1.model = t2.model
      AND t1.catcode= t2.catcode
)
```

Comment: yes i understand but the result is some kind strange
if t1 records are more than t2 
i should have the same number in t2 or i'm missing some logic here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - the query will return all records from `t1` where those three fields have matching values in `t2`.

Comment: yes, i got it now , thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to exists, this will only get you records from t1 that exist in t2.

```
select distinct
       t1.make, t1.model, t1.catcode
from t1 join t2 on (t1.make = t2.make
                    and t1.model = t2.model
                    and t1.catcode = t2.catcode)
```